# C#: Easiest way to initialize & populate this particular 2D/3D Dictionary?

Tags: c#, dictionary, containers, game-engine

I have a bit of a complex dictionary.

It's a dictionary which holds two enumerated types & a List<>

```
Dictionary<BiomeType, Dictionary<LocationType, List<string>>> myDictionary;
```

So when I want to use it, I do something like this:

```
//Add "myString" to the List<string>
myDictionary[BiomeType.Jungle][LocationType.City1].Add("myString"));
```

When I try to add "myString" to myList, it throws an obvious & foreseeable error: "KeyNotFoundException: The given key was not present in the dictionary."

Is there any way in C# to automatically have the Dictionary add the Key if it isn't already there? I have a lot of BiomeTypes & even more LocationTypes. It would be a PITA to have to create each List, then create each locationtype dictionary, and then to add it for every BiomeType. All that work just to initialize this complex dictionary. Is there no easy way to do this?

I'm using this for gamedev, to store objects in a Dictionary, so I can access them by doing something like

```
BiomeType playerCurrentBiomeType;
LocationType playerCurrentLocationType;
LoadLevel(myDictionary[playerCurrentBiomeType][playerCurrentLocationType]);

//ex. myDictionary[BiomeType.Jungle][LocationType.CapitalCity]
//ex. myDictionary[BiomeType.Desert][LocationType.CapitalCity]
//ex. myDictionary[BiomeType.Desert][LocationType.City3]
```

Comment: It's obviously implied here that anyone could easily initialize the dictionary the normal way by simply adding everything line by line. However as I mentioned, that is a huge PITA creating list after list, then creating new dictionarys populated by those lists, and then finally adding those dictionarys to the other dictionary. Just checking if there's an easier way.

Comment: I also know I could simply not use one dictionary to hold everything, and instead create a single dictionary for each biome, or something along those lines. However I liked the idea of simply grabbing all the objects in a single container by just using BiomeType/LocationType. Seemed simpler.

Comment: C# does not know anything about `Dictionary`, so no there is no easier way. You'll need to write code to do this.

Comment: @Carter81 highly recommend reading [ESR's guide](http://catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html) if you want to be the best member of SO you can be.

Comment: Carter, I suggest, if you want help from more answerers with good reputations here, that you cooperate with your critics a little more. Writing questions that are accepted and get good answers here isn't easy. I have trouble getting my questions accepted sometimes too. Try to demonstrate that you've already made an effort to solve this problem yourself, and that will go a long way towards getting past the criticisms to the answers you want. I think if you do that you'll get a far better experience here going forward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply looping through every possible enum type & adding in a new value works to fully populate this multi-dimensional dictionary.

```
    Dictionary<BiomeType, Dictionary<LocationType, List<string>>> myDictionary = new Dictionary<BiomeType, Dictionary<LocationType, List<string>>>(); //No thanks to troll users like Peter.
    foreach (BiomeType biomeType in System.Enum.GetValues(typeof(BiomeType)))
    {
        Dictionary<LocationType, List<string>> newLocDict = new Dictionary<LocationType, List<string>>(); //No thanks to troll users like Peter.

        foreach (LocationType locType in System.Enum.GetValues(typeof(LocationType)))
        {
            List<string> newList = new List<string>(); 
            newLocDict.Add(locType, newList); //Add the final bit here & voila! Finished! No thanks to troll users like Peter.
        }

        myDictionary.Add(biomeType, newLocDict);
    }
```

Robyn's solution works the same way if you don't want to fully populate the container with ALL enum values.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps, you can try this:

```
Dictionary<BiomeType, Dictionary<LocationType, List<string>>> myDictionary = new Dictionary<BiomeType, Dictionary<LocationType, List<string>>>();

BiomeType playerCurrentBiomeType;
LocationType playerCurrentLocationType;

if(!myDictionary.ContainsKey(playerCurrentBiomeType))
{
    myDictionary.Add(playerCurrentBiomeType, new Dictionary<LocationType , List<string>>{{playerCurrentLocationType, new List<string>()}}); 
}

myDictionary[playerCurrentBiomeType][playerCurrentLocationType].Add("bla");
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do this (although to be honest I'm not sure you should!)

The class below is a type that generally acts like a dictionary, does what you asked for, and has some other changes to hide from you the empty items it creates every time you ask the indexer for an item that doesn't exist.

```
public class SmellyDictionary<T1, T2>: IDictionary<T1, T2>, ICollection where T2 : ICollection, new()
{
    private readonly IDictionary<T1, T2> _dict = new Dictionary<T1, T2>();

    public T2 this[T1 key]
    {
        get
        {
            T2 value;
            if (!_dict.TryGetValue(key, out value))
                _dict[key] = value = new T2(); // This stinks!
            return value;
        }
        set { _dict[key] = value; }
    }

    public bool Contains(KeyValuePair<T1, T2> item)
    {
        return _dict.Contains(item);
    }

    public bool ContainsKey(T1 key)
    {
        return _dict.ContainsKey(key) && _dict[key].Count > 0; // This hides the smell
    }

    public int Count { get { return _dict.Count(kvp => kvp.Value.Count > 0); } } // This hides the smell

    public void Add(T1 key, T2 value)
    {
        T2 currentValue;
        if (_dict.TryGetValue(key, out currentValue) && currentValue.Count > 0)
            throw new ArgumentException("A non empty element with the same key already exists in the SmellyDictionary");
        _dict[key] = value;
    }

    public void Add(KeyValuePair<T1, T2> item)
    {
        Add(item.Key, item.Value);
    }

    public bool Remove(T1 key)
    {
        return _dict.Remove(key);
    }

    public bool Remove(KeyValuePair<T1, T2> item)
    {
        return _dict.Remove(item);
    }

    public bool TryGetValue(T1 key, out T2 value)
    {
        return _dict.TryGetValue(key, out value);
    }

    public ICollection<T1> Keys { get { return _dict.Keys; } }
    public ICollection<T2> Values { get { return _dict.Values; } }
    public object SyncRoot { get { return ((ICollection)_dict).SyncRoot; } }
    public bool IsSynchronized { get { return ((ICollection)_dict).IsSynchronized; } }

    public IEnumerator<KeyValuePair<T1, T2>> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return _dict.GetEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }

    public void Clear()
    {
        _dict.Clear();
    }

    public void CopyTo(Array array, int index)
    {
        _dict.CopyTo((KeyValuePair<T1, T2>[])array, index);
    }

    public void CopyTo(KeyValuePair<T1, T2>[] array, int arrayIndex)
    {
        _dict.CopyTo(array, arrayIndex);
    }

    public bool IsReadOnly { get { return _dict.IsReadOnly; } }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a slightly more sensible option. Just call this method to add a string to your dictionary.

```
    private void AddCityToDictionary(Dictionary<BiomeType, Dictionary<LocationType, List<string>>> myDictionary, BiomeType biome, LocationType location, string city)
    {
        Dictionary<LocationType, List<string>> locationDictionary;
        if (!myDictionary.TryGetValue(biome, out locationDictionary))
            locationDictionary = myDictionary[biome] = new Dictionary<LocationType, List<string>>();
        List<string> cityList;
        if (!locationDictionary.TryGetValue(location, out cityList))
            cityList = locationDictionary[location] = new List<string>();
        cityList.Add(city);
    }
```